Calculating the expected value for a complicated pdf
I am given the following cdf (cumulative distribution function) for the random variable $T$ with support $x\in(0, \theta)$. $$F_{T}(x)=\Bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{n}}{\theta}\Bigg)^{n}$$ I am asked to calculate the expected value for $T$. For that, I have calculated the pdf (probability distribution function) of $T$ given that $$\frac{d}{dx}F_{T}(x)=f_{T}(x)$$ where $f_{T}(x)$ is the pdf for $T$. Derivating I get $$f_{T}(x)=\frac{n}{\theta}\Bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{n}}{\theta}\Bigg)^{n-1}$$ So to compute the expected I must be able to compute $$\mathbb{E}(T)=\int_{0}^{\theta}x\frac{n}{\theta}\Bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{n}}{\theta}\Bigg)^{n-1}dx=\frac{n}{\theta^n}\int_{0}^{\theta}x\Big(x-\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{n-1}dx=\frac{n}{\theta^n}A$$ The thing is that I don't find success in calculating $A$, Wolfram Alpha doesn't either. Can anyone please help me? I have tried many analysis results but any of them seem to work.

What is $n$? Just a fixed number?

Yes, it is a fixed number, although in this context is called a parameter I think.

Have you tried substituting $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{n}$?

I mean, It is still difficult to compute, $\int_{0}^{\theta}x(x-\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}dx=\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\theta-\frac{1}{n}}(y+\frac{1}{n})y^{n-1}dy=\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\theta-\frac{1}{n}}y^ndy+\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\theta-\frac{1}{n}}y^{n-1}dy=A+\frac{1}{n}B$. Now, each of the integrals comes out to be $A=\frac{(\theta-\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}+(-\frac{1}{n})^{n+2}}{n+1}$ and $B=\frac{(\theta-\frac{1}{n})^n+(-\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}}{n}$

@HornyPigeon54: and that is an answer. Do you expect a simpler expression?

Something seems wrong with your CDF. We have $F(0)=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n\theta)^n}$ while it should be zero. Likewise for $F(\theta)$, which should be $1$, but isn't.

It cannot be a cdf with support $x\in(0, \theta)$ as we should have $F(\theta)=1$ and $F(0)=0,$ which is not the case for $F_{T}(x)=\Bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{n}}{\theta}\Bigg)^{n}.$
